# error expected primary-expression before ';' token

Tags: c++

Hello i have problem with this code

***Armor.h***

```
#ifdenf armor
#define armor
class Armor {

private:
    int m_weight;

public:
    Armor(int weight);

};
#endif
```

***Knight.h***

```
#ifndef knight
#define knight

#include "Armor.h"
class Knight {
private:
    Armor* m_armor;
    string m_name;
    int m_strength;

public:
    Knight(string name, int strength);

    void setArmor(Armor* armor);
};
#endif
```

***Knight.cpp***

```
#include "Knight.h"
void Knight::setArmor(Armor* armor){
    m_armor = armor; // error occurred

}
```

**Error: error: expected primary-expression before ';' token**

thanks for help

Comment: you should add a ; after Knight class definition.

Comment: Use a better compiler: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/96a41bfedf9dd78c `error: expected ';' after class` (also, as said, you should protect your headers from multiple inclusion with _include guards_)

Comment: After your edit (which indicates that you _didn't_ post the _real_ code to begin with...): `#define armor` then later `m_armor = armor;`, don't you see the problem?

Comment: "Hello i have problem with this code" -- like maybe that it won't compile because the very first line is illegal? As noted, post the real code that you're compiling, not made up stuff that is likely to have *different* errors in it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#define armor
```

Now you can't use the name `armor` in any source file that includes this header. The preprocessor will remove it.

```
m_armor = armor; // error occurred
```

Whoops! The preprocessor turns that into

```
m_armor = ;
```

I suggest using the convention of `ALL_CAPS` for macros, and not for anything else, so that they can't stomp over regular code. You might also consider `#pragma once` rather than a macro-based include guard, although that's not guaranteed to be portable.

Comment: Moral - post the actual code giving the error then you will get an answer sooner.

Comment: It is obviously (or should be obviously) a bad practice to use as include guards identifiers that are likely to be used in the code. Try something more like `#ifndef ARMOR_HEADER_FILE_INCLUDE_GUARD` ... or #pragma once which works these days with all major implementations.

Answer (score 3):

Don't forget to close your `Knight` class declaration with a semicolon!

(Out of interest this is required in C++, not in Java).

Answer (score 3):

You do need include guards.

**Edit**

Assuming the edit to the question, which gives include guards actually uses `armor` as follows,

```
#ifdenf armor //<<--- ARE YOU POSTING THE ACTUAL CODE... try #ifndef
#define armor
//...
#endif
```

You then try to use `armor` as a variable name. Try

```
#ifndef ARMOR_INCLUDED
#define ARMOR_INCLUDED
//...
#endif
```

instead

**End Edit**

Also, class `Knight` needs a trailing semicolon.

```
class Knight {
private:
    Armor* m_armor;
    string m_name;
    int m_strength;

public:
    Knight(string name, int strength);

    void setArmor(Armor* armor);
}; //<----------
```

As a general rule, if you get a compile error about syntax on one line, which looks OK, work backwards to see if something earlier is causing it.

Comment: Are you posting *exactly* the code that causes the error? It works on my machine.

Comment: i strip some junk but it was only variabiles and two virtual functions

Comment: The "junk" must be causing the problem then - correct the question with code that actually causes the problem on your machine

Answer (score 2):

In `Knight.h` the class definition is missing a `;`:

```
class Knight {
    ...
};
```

Without the `;` the following token is interpreted as a symbol. In your code (`Knight.cpp`) it is the code immediately following the include directive. `void` is not a legal symbol, and this triggers the error.